# emacs24.3 / 24.4 for MS Windows always stops working when closing window

Tags: windows, emacs, windows-8.1

I downloaded emacs 24.4 binary for Windows 32bit from [gnu official repository](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/). After I unpacked the zip archive, emacs.exe  seems to work fine apparently. But when closing window, it stop working. Following error message occurs on console.

**[console]**

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more infomation
```

**[screenshot]**
[image]

I tried emacs24.3, and emacs25.05(trunk). But the same problems occurs.
Does anyone know workaround for this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**OS** : Windows 8.1 Pro 32bit

Comment: How are you closing it? The "normal way" to close Emacs is to do `C-x C-c`.

Comment: As a side note, the Windows version of Emacs should be started with `bin\runemacs.exe`, not `bin\emacs.exe`. This is essentially a wrapper that launches Emacs without that `cmd.exe` window.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your rapid response. Although I also tried bin\runemacs.exe, it ended up with the same result. In order to close the window, I tried two ways. by C-x C-c and by closing window button.

Comment: Use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Provide a recipe to repro the problem. The recipe should start with invoking Emacs using `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is maybe  dependent on the settings of my windows computer.
After following procedure, the problem doesn't happen. and emacs24.4 works fine.

1. Uninstalled MinGW toolchain

   - I had installed MinGW in C:\MinGW directory. so I deleted it.
2. Removed MinGW path and old emacs binary path from PATH (environment variable)

I don't know why it fixs the problem. but I think it affected emacs-24.4 indirectly.